# Oracle trigger to check course duration in one table and prevent update if course is a particular date

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Apologies in advanced if the question that I am asking has already been answered elsewhere, however I have had difficulty locating a suitable answer. I know how to create simple triggers based on one table, however what I am trying to achieve links updates across two tables. Here is the scenario: In the course table is a duration column and in the offerings table there is a start_date column. An offering is an instance where a course is offered and the two tables (course and offering) are linked by course_id. I need to create a trigger that prevents the offerings table from having a start date during January if the course which is corresponds to has a 5 day duration. I have attempted to create this trigger and can post my efforts but I am absolutely way off I'm sure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_duration
  BEFORE UPDATE on offering
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT c.duration
  INTO duration
  FROM course c
  WHERE c.duration = 5
IF(:new.start_date BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYY') AND to_date('31/01/2013', 'DD/MM/YYY')
  THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(20100, 'Cannot run particular course during this month')
END IF;
END;
```

Course table:

```
Course_id(pk) | Title | Duration | Cost
```

Offering table:

```
offering_id(pk) | start_date | location | instructor | course_id(fk)
```

There are also two other tables Attendance and Student i don't think i need to post the construct of these tables for this question

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: post your code.  triggers can easily run a query, then it is up to what you actually want to do with the results.

Comment: What happens if the duration is later changed to 5 days (and records exist in offerings that then violate the rule?)

Comment: Hi tim, the durations are fixed

Comment: I'd put the duration in the offerings table.

Comment: Your select against course table does not specify which course.  Offering has a courseid column, right?

Comment: Hi yes it does, how would I reference that in the above? The table construct is fixed so I cannot move duration

Comment: What's the link between COURSE and OFFERING?  I'm guessing that an OFFERING is an instance where a COURSE is offered, or available to be taken.  Please update your question with the definitions of these tables.  Thanks.

Comment: @Matthew you have to notice the Tim's messages. You must create two triggers: one for COURSE and one for OFFERING. These triggers are needed for checking referential integrity on both sides cause you can break it by changing data in one or another table.

Comment: @knagaev this has to be achieved with a single trigger. Is it possible? I haven't had a chance to test the proposed solutions below yet but will do shortly

Comment: @Matthew No, you can't. Imagine if you update OFFERING and check the condition in COURSE table. The course that corresponds offering was 4 days long and the trigger permitted start_date in January. But later you changed duration of the course to 5 days and your constraint became broken.

Comment: @Knagaev i understand the flaw in it, but let's say once duration is set it is permanently fixed (which is the scenario i am working with) then is it possible - bare in mind this is not for a live working environment

Comment: @Matthew there are no permanent things if you didn't create a constraint. But it's only your decision, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to tweak this if there's any new information about the tables, but here's an initial stab based on your comment that there's a courseid column in the `offering` table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_duration
  BEFORE UPDATE on offering
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  isFound NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- Just want to know if there's a duration 5 record for the course...
  SELECT 1 INTO isFound FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM course c
    WHERE c.course_id = :NEW.course_id AND c.duration = 5);
  -- Fallthrough to here means a course was found with duration 5. Is
  -- it scheduled for January (month #1) of any year?
  IF EXTRACT(MONTH FROM :NEW.start_date) = 1 THEN
    THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(20100, 'Cannot run particular course during this month');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  -- If the query didn't find a course with duration 5 it throws
  -- a NO_DATA_FOUND exception. Ignore the exception because not
  -- finding a course means it's OK to add the row.
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
```

Comment: You can avoid an exception with "select count(*)"

Comment: Excellent point @knagaev, thanks! I usually reach for "if exists" when I need just one hit because it's a lot faster if there are tons of matching rows for the count. But in this case there probably aren't and a count would probably be easier for the OP to understand, and that's important. There's no indication that the OP has tried this, but if they do and have trouble understanding the exception handling I'll rework it to use COUNT.

Comment: @EdGibbs Thanks for your help, i have attempted your suggestion however i get the following error - Error(7,24): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.COURSEID' - any ideas?

Comment: @Matthew - that means you don't have a `courseid` column on your `offering` table. I thought from the comments above that you did. Can you post your `course` and `offering` table structures? That'll help me and all the folks involved in the thread.

Comment: @EdGibbs there is a course_id column in offering table which is an FK of the course_id in course table, i will post the table construct now

Comment: Thanks; that'll help. I'll alter my answer to change both instances of `courseid` to `course_id`.

Comment: @edgibbs i have amended it and it compiled without errors, thank's for your help

Comment: Excellent, but compilation's just half the battle :) Let us all know if you run into any logic errors. Good luck!